# Make CrawlSpider Process data on HomePage + Other Extracted Links

Tags: scrapy

I am doing a broad crawl.  I need to process a few pages per website in order to set values for one of about 20 classification rules.  For example, one classification rule is "Has Phone Number" (runs a regex to see if there is a phone number in the page source and returns a boolean).  The rules are implemented in a function called parse_page().

I need the CrawlSpider to run parse_page() on the homepage of each crawled website, as well as other common pages such the about page, contact page, privacy policy page, etc.

When I run the spider, it starts with some-site.com and grabs the pages according to the Rule definitions in the code below.

My problem lies in that I need parse_page() to run on the *homepage* of some-site.com (parse_page()
currently only runs on some-site.com/contact-us, some-site.com/about-us, etc.).  My question then is: **How do I specify a Rule() to include the homepage of the site, so that parse_page() will get called for the homepage as well as the other pages already included?**

```
class SomeBotSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
     name = 'some_bot'
     allowed_domains = ['some-site.com']
     start_urls = ['https://some-site.com/']


      rules = (
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/contact'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='disclaimer'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='disclosure'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/about'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='privacy'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the [`parse_start_url`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) method of the spider. The first request to website(homepage url) is handled by `parse_start_url` method. You can call `parse_page` inside the `parse_start_url`  method.
Something like this:

```
class SomeBotSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = 'some_bot'
    allowed_domains = ['some-site.com']
    start_urls = ['https://some-site.com/']


    rules = (
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/contact'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='disclaimer'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='disclosure'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/about'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
         Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='privacy'), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
     )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_page(response)
```

Comment: Hi asimhashmi -- I tried your suggestion (it thought it made a lot of sense) and overrode the parse method according to your code.  When I run my project again, I get the exact same result.  I am not sure why it didn't change the behavior of the spider...

Comment: parse() is never invoked (at least, the overridden version) by the first request to the website.  

`[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://some-site.com> (referer: None)`

^^ scrapy.core.engine is calling some-site.com.

For the subsequent pages:

`[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://some-site.com/contact-us> (referrer: https://some-site.com)
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://some-site.com/contact-us/`

The [scrapy.core.scraper] output does not appear for the initial page at all.

Comment: my bad, it should be `parse_start_url`, I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you.  Overriding parse_start_url did the trick!